# Fazendo Downlod de diretórios WINDOWS

Tags: c++

Tenho uma aplicação que transfere arquivos via socket, porém e muito cansativo ter que fazer transferências de um a um. Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Como posso fazer download de um **DIRETÓRIO** completo via socket?

O programa funciona da seguinte forma, ele pede para que o usuário digite o diretório remoto no qual se encontra o arquivo para transferência, EXEMPLO: **C:\USERS\ARQUIVO.DAT**
depois ele faz uma validação para confirmar a existência do arquivo, e por ultimo ele transfere o arquivo byte a byte.

O problema é que quando o usuário passa apenas o diretório ele falha na validação,
um exemplo é se eu digitar **C:\USERS\DIRETORIO**
o programa então retorna um erro de **FAILED IN READ BYTES**

A solução seria zipar o diretório, porém o servidor trabalha apenas com linhas de comando "**SHELL**", e o Windows não tem nada nativo para zipar por linha de comando.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção para isso é mandar aplicar esse processo sobre cada arquivo do diretório:

```
#include <dirent.h>

struct stat st;
lstat(caminho, &st);
if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)){
    //Se for diretório
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir (caminho)) != NULL) {
      // Abre o diretório
      while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
           //Passa por cada arquivo no diretório
           enviarArquivo(ent->d_name);
      }
      closedir (dir);
    } else {
      /* Erro abrindo diretório */
      perror ("");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
} else {
    //Se não for diretório
    enviarArquivo(caminho);
}
```

Adaptado de:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536781/accessing-directories-in-c/3536853#3536853

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c